# How can I unlock all campaigns in HOMM 3?

Tags: heroes-of-might-and-magic-3

I have Heroes of Might and Magic 3 Complete. I'd like to play the initially locked campaigns that get unlocked after you beat the entire available list. Is there a way to do it without beating the entire list, e.g. by using some 3rd party unlocker, obtaining a saved game, etc.? And if so, where can I get that tool/saved game/whatever?

Comment: Heroes 3 has in-game cheatcodes. I can't remember if there's either an "advance to level X" or "win current map" code, though.

Answer (score 6):

As per Raven Dreamer's comment, there is a cheat code you can use to automatically win each map.  Start the map, press <kbd>TAB</kbd> and then enter **nwctrojanrabbit** and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.  You should be able to do that on each map to finish the campaign and unlock the next campaigns.

There is also [a saved game that can be downloaded](http://www.heroesofmightandmagic.com/heroes3/Campaigns%20Completed.CGM) which has all of the campaigns unlocked.

Comment: What does nwc mean?

Comment: @Pacerier - [New World Computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_World_Computing) - the original developer of the Heroes of Might and Magic series.

Answer (score 2):

Per au revoir's answer, you can use a code to instantly beat levels. 
 But, cheat codes are version-specific.  *nwctrojanrabbit* doesn't work for HOMM3 Complete edition.  For that, you need *nwcredpill* instead.

http://www.heroesofmightandmagic.com/heroes3sod/cheatcodes.shtml

P.S. I ran into this problem because I kept starting new campaigns from the main menu instead of by loading a saved game.  Unlocked campaigns are save-specific, NOT universal!

Answer (score 1):

What if you import 3rd party saved game where all companies are passed? Just move a saved game files to the correspondent HoMMs directory (somewhere in ../Users/AppData/...). Then load it and launch/relaunch.

I haven't ever tried that - just an idea..